кто может помочь с этим кодом? проблема с импортом
from aiogram.filters import Command, StateFilter, F

from aiogram.filters import Command, StateFilter, F

@dp.message(StateFilter(Form.waiting_for_phone), F.contact)

@dp.message(StateFilter(Form.waiting_for_location), F.location)
ImportError: cannot import name 'F' from 'aiogram.filters'


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

А что такое F? Функция?

Магические фильтры
Магические фильтры, как по мне, это самое глобальное и самое крутое обновление которое предложила своим пользователям библиотека aiogram 3 за долгое время. Грамотное использование этого нововведения позволяет разработчикам сокращать код, на фоне двойки, в полтора-два раза и это без преувеличений!
В прошлых статьях мы уже касались магических фильтров в таких реализациях:
F.text == “ПРИВЕТ” (тем самым мы говорили что бот должен реагировать на сообщение “ПРИВЕТ”)

Магические фильтры отвечающие по типу контента.
Да, друзья, в тройке больше не работает запись content_type=ContentType.TEXT, к примеру, тут эта запись сократилась, тем самым облегчив жизнь разработчику.
Вот как теперь записывается фильтры на тип сообщения:
F.text – обычное текстовое сообщение (уже такое делали)
F.photo – cообщение с фото
F.video – сообщение с видео
F.animation – сообщение с анимацией (гифки)
F.contact – сообщение с отправкой контактных данных (очень полезно для FSM)
F.document – сообщение с файлом (тут может быть и фото, если оно отправлено документом)

не могу понять почему не работают в этом скрипте, скрипт написан с использованием 3.xx библиотекой

Посмотрите вот здесь: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html что и как Вы импортируете. Там есть и такое: from aiogram import F

Вот здесь скорее всего Ваши проблемы: The magic_filter package implements class shortly named magic_filter.F that’s mean F can be imported from aiogram or magic_filter. F is alias for MagicFilter.

Решилось импортом
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F

Ссылки по теме еще с решениями
https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/1136
https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-3.x/examples/finite_state_machine.py
